# How do I make the items in Column A of Sheet 1 appear in Column A of Sheet 2 in the same workbook in MS Excel

Tags: excel

How do I make the items in Column A of Sheet 1 appear in Column A of Sheet 2 in the same workbook in MS Excel so that whenever an item is added to Column A, Sheet 1, it automatically appears in Column A, Sheet 2

Answer (score 3):

First put the formular inside Sheet2 column A like this

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

Then copy the cell we just put the formular, After that select whole column A on Sheet2 and do a right click -> select `Paste special` -> `Paste formular only`

Beware, it will make the whole column on Sheet 2 have the formular.

So If you know extractly how many column will match with column on Sheet1, I sugest use answer from @Anastasios Selmanis

Answer (score 2):

Just do the following.

1. Go to sheet 2.
2. In the **first row** of column **A** wright `"=Sheet1!A1"` . [image]
3. Then copy the value of the cell to all the cells of column **A** of **Sheet2** by dragging down the cell
   [image]